# Getting conflicting types error when trying to include a file

Tags: c, file, struct

I have the following files (for example, this isn't my real project):
`file1.h`:

```
typedef struct TestStruct{
    int a;
    int b;
} testStruct;
int doSomething();
```

`file2.h`:

```
#include "file1.h"
void doAnotherThing(testStruct a);
```

`file3.h`:

```
#include "file1.h"
void anotherFunction(testStruct a);
```

The .c files don't matter in this case. Now, I have a file called `file4.c`, which includes both file2 and file3. This gives off the following error:

```
file1.h:1:16: error: redefinition of ‘struct TestStruct’
 typedef struct TestStruct{
                ^
In file included from file3.c:1:0:
file1.h:1:16: note: originally defined here
 typedef struct TestStruct{
                ^
In file included from file3.h:1:0,
                 from file3.c:2:
file1.h:4:3: error: conflicting types for ‘testStruct’
 } testStruct;
   ^
In file included from file3.c:1:0:
file1.h:4:3: note: previous declaration of ‘testStruct’ was here
 } testStruct;
```

Which, as far as I understand it, is caused by both file2 and file3 including the same file. What way do I have of fixing this issue?

Comment: What is unclear with the error message? Do you have known about header guards?

Comment: Somehow I missed the whole concept of header guards, I'll be sure to check it out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add include guards to file1.h to make sure its contents don't get included twice:

```
#ifndef FILE1_H
#define FILE1_H

typedef struct TestStruct{
    int a;
    int b;
} testStruct;
int doSomething();

#endif
```